# Connect-gzip-static doesn't pick up html in firefox

Tags: browser-sync

I found this [tutorial](https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/tree/master/recipes/server.gzipped.assets), which talks about how to serve with pre-gzipped assets example with browser-sync.

It picks up `*.html`, `*.css`, `*.js`, `*.{jpg,png}` in firefox v51.0.1 (current version), but with the previous version (v50), it generates 404 error with `.html` file but find pre-gzipped file to another file.

I understand that it doesn't find the file, because into pre-gzipped assets, files are `.*.gzip`.

What I do not understand is, why firefox lt 51 doesn't render the file that `connect-gzip-static`tells it to render.

Here's my bs-config.js:

```
var Environement = require("./env");
var indexFile = Environement.enableProd ? '/index.html' : '/index_dev.html';
var middleware  = require('connect-gzip-static')('./web_app');

module.exports = {
  notify: false,
  logLevel: "silent",
  server: {
    middleware: {      
      0: null,     // removes default `connect-logger` middleware
      1: require('connect-history-api-fallback')({
        index: indexFile
      }),
      2: middleware
    }
  },
  ghostMode: false
};
```

Is there another way to solve this problem?
Is there anybody here who has encountered the same problem as me?

*Note:* With chrome, IE Edge and FF v51, it works perfectly.